# Is there an API to fetch Twitter Periscope live video statistics

Tags: twitter, statistics, periscope

I've a requirement to fetch Twitter Periscope live video stats, I looked for twitter APIs and found APIs to fetch tweet and media engagement, so can I use them to fetch live video stats as well, because Live video is also posted as a tweet, is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Periscope broadcasts can be shared to the Twitter timeline, but they don’t have to be. If you’re only interested in the stats of Periscope streams that have also been shared to Twitter, then yes your assumption is correct. However, if your goal is broader and you’re interested in stats for any Periscope stream, then using the Twitter media engagement API is not sufficient.

Periscope does have its own API. It’s not public, but you can find some unofficial doco here:

https://static.pmmlabs.ru/OpenPeriscope

Using this API it is possible to get some stats, like view counts on a broadcast, using unauthenticated calls like /getBroadcastPublic, but to get more detailed stats you need to call either /getBroadcastViewers or /broadcastSummary, which require an auth token. It all depends on what kind of stats you’re looking for.